# Are there differences between the standard C preprocessor and the Objective-C preprocessor?

Tags: objective-c

I can't seem to find an answer to this question by Googling. Can I assume that the Objective-C preprocessor works exactly identically to the C preprocessor, and that anything I read about the C preprocessor applies exactly the same way in an Objective C environment? Or are there subtle differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some subtle differences:

- The include paths are different depending on what language you are using.
- I believe that `#import` triggers a warning if you're not using ObjC.
- The preprocessor may have some special cases to handle the ObjC `@"string"` syntax.
- And, of course, most importantly, the language affects which macros are predefined (e.g, `__objc__`).

It's still `cpp` either way, though -- it's just operating in a different mode.

Comment: this doesn't seem a good answer. "I believe that..." and "The preprocessor may...". It's not definitive enough. Also as for the @ symbols, the preprocessor does not seem to replace them so the compiler must be dealing with them

Comment: WRT. @ symbols, the preprocessor is somewhat aware of double-quoted strings (e.g, it will not substitute macros or strip comments inside them), and the same awareness is applied to `@""` strings. I'm not certain whether this is because the preprocessor has been "taught" about these strings or because it doesn't care, but either way the result is the same. WRT. `#import` warnings, it's simply a difference in the options passed to `cpp` by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) from Apple states that Obj-C is a small superset to the language. As far as I can tell, the preprocessor is the same as regular C's (It's all based on the same open-source components, anyway). That's true with the GCC compiler (which is used elsewhere) and related tools; I would assume LLVM is the same as well but I can't speak for the latter.

Of note would be `#pragma`s, but then again they were meant to be implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same preprocessor. You can look at the Clang or GCC source if you want to see for yourself — as far as I can tell, aside from the fact that it uses the Objective-C lexer rather than the C one, it's the same.